# WARNING .../myproject/target/classes (Is a directory) when <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar> set

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

This is a nuisance more than a bug (I hope).  I see this warning even when I do a simple "Helloworld" executable uber.jar using the maven-shaded-plugin (latest to date).

I want to get rid of this warning or correct my configuration.  Does anyone have any insight to this warning?  Is anyone else getting this warning.

Answer (score 0):

There's a PR that should fix this: https://github.com/apache/maven-shade-plugin/pull/83

Comment: A shaded plug-in developer insisted it wasn’t a bug. Thanks for acknowledging that in fact it was a bug and not a configuration issue on my part.